# eclipse cygwin printf no output on debug

Tags: c, eclipse, console, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I managed to get cygwin to work with eclipse and made the default hello world program. Running the program is fine and it outputs correctly in console. But when I debug and step through the program, printf statements does not appear in console. Is there a setting somewhere that I need to change?

Answer (score 2):

You should add this once or after every `printf`

```
fflush(stdout);
```

For reasons I don't really know, the program output will occur only at the end of the program. Putting this call will force the output everytime there is a **printf**